# onclick post this value to textarea

Tags: jquery, onclick

Ok we are making a unicode form, basically user clicks a button ( href link ) and I would like the value of that sent and posted into a textarea.

link is like so

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button" title="type - lol">&#x263b</a>
```

textarea like so:

```
<textarea id="text-to-copy" cols="48" id="textarea" rows="5" onfocus="if(this.value=='type your text here ...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='type your text here ...';">type your text here ...</textarea>
```

Any ideas please.

Please note we have multiple hrefs, that a user could click to post into the textarea.

eg.

```
    <a href="javascript:;" class="button" title="type - heart or love">&#x2665</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="button" title="type - club">&#x2663</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="button" title="type - lol">&#x263b</a>
```

Comment: do you want the value to be added (appended ?) to the current content or overwrite the current content ?

Comment: Do you want to replace the content of the textarea by the new value or insert it?

Comment: overwrite it, the placeholder focus text can go.

Comment: Your in-line JavaScript suggests you're not using jQuery, but plain JavaScript. Is the jQuery tag accurate?

Comment: the only javascript I have posted is javascript:; because hash tags muck up page, and yep we are using jquery David :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   $("#text-to-copy").text($(this).html());
});
```

This will set the text in the textarea to be the text from the `a`

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/BHCdJ/1/

or append :

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#text-to-copy").text() == "type your text here ...") {
        $("#text-to-copy").text($(this).html());
    } else {
        $("#text-to-copy").text($("#text-to-copy").text() + $(this).html());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/BHCdJ/2/

Comment: thats great, but if we use multiple elements, then they overwrite each other in succession

Comment: bugger... your example works.. mine doesnt live argghh I added js like so ( noticed you are using edge ? )
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#text-to-copy").text() == "type your text here ...") {
   $("#text-to-copy").text($(this).html());
    } else {
        $("#text-to-copy").text($("#text-to-copy").text() + $(this).html());
    }
});
}
</script>

Comment: you can change the jQuery version on the left of the jsfiddle ... what version are you using ? and what happens when you click the link ? what errors are you getting in the JavaScript console ?

Comment: 1.5.4 its annoying i cant email u our page link.

Comment: Fixed, our tooltip was dynamically adding span classes to innerhtml. All solved thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if am wrong. But if thats what you want, then drop the textarea and use a div element. And use javascript's `appendChild` method to append span elements whose textContent would bear the value of the anchor.

And to make your div element behave like a text area use the contentEditable attribute and set max-width and max-height to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this function. I like to use jQuery to do tasks like this. It will clear the textarea case it has the default text and then append the content.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addEmoticon(this)" class="button" title="type - lol">&#x263b</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addEmoticon(el){
if (document.getElementById('text-to-copy').value == 'type your text here ...'){
    document.getElementById('text-to-copy').value = '';
}
document.getElementById('text-to-copy').value += el.innerHTML
}
</script>
```

Comment: thats nigh on perfect but it isnt passing the value of a it is passing the value of everything.. bugger so CLOSE !! well done

Comment: Just relooking at your code, and It does work. My issue which I didnt explain is , each element (a) has a tooltip, which is within span tags within the innerhtml, so these are getting parsed onclick. Is there a way of preventing this.. aside from disabling the tooltips?

Comment: Typically console view:
<a class="button colorTipContainer pinkone" onclick="addEmoticon(this)" href="javascript:;">
♥
<span class="colorTip" style="margin-left: -82px; display: none;">
type - heart or love
<span class="pointyTipShadow"></span>
<span class="pointyTip"></span>
</span>
</a>
As you can see everything within innerhtml is getting parsed, if I can prevent span to span stuff then its a goer